# How can I pin a certificate with Square OKHTTP?

Tags: android, okhttp

I think I need to create a new SSL Socket Factory?
Also, I don't want to use the global SSL Context (https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/184) for obvious reasons.

thanks!

**EDIT:**

As of okhttp 2.1.0 you can pin certificates very easily.

See [the source code here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/83090befcca69b44c257b96afb519ca66282ca63/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/CertificatePinner.java#L43) to get started

Comment: Check here the simplest solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45855405/3448003

Answer (score 95, accepted):

### UPDATE FOR OKHTTP 3.0

OKHTTP 3.0 has [built-in support](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html) for pinning certificates. Start off by pasting the following code:

```
 String hostname = "yourdomain.com";
 CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
     .add(hostname, "sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=")
     .build();
 OkHttpClient client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
     .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
     .build();

 Request request = new Request.Builder()
     .url("https://" + hostname)
     .build();
 client.newCall(request).execute();
```

This will fail because `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` is not a valid hash of your certificate. The exception thrown will have the correct hashes of your certificate:

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate pinning failure!
   Peer certificate chain:
     sha256/afwiKY3RxoMmLkuRW1l7QsPZTJPwDS2pdDROQjXw8ig=: CN=publicobject.com, OU=PositiveSSL
     sha256/klO23nT2ehFDXCfx3eHTDRESMz3asj1muO+4aIdjiuY=: CN=COMODO RSA Secure Server CA
     sha256/grX4Ta9HpZx6tSHkmCrvpApTQGo67CYDnvprLg5yRME=: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
     sha256/lCppFqbkrlJ3EcVFAkeip0+44VaoJUymbnOaEUk7tEU=: CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   Pinned certificates for publicobject.com:
     sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
   at okhttp3.CertificatePinner.check(CertificatePinner.java)
   at okhttp3.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java)
   at okhttp3.Connection.connect(Connection.java)
   at okhttp3.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java)
```

Make sure you add these to your CertificatePinner object, and you have successfully pinned your certificate:

```
 CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
   .add("publicobject.com", "sha256/afwiKY3RxoMmLkuRW1l7QsPZTJPwDS2pdDROQjXw8ig=")
   .add("publicobject.com", "sha256/klO23nT2ehFDXCfx3eHTDRESMz3asj1muO+4aIdjiuY=")
   .add("publicobject.com", "sha256/grX4Ta9HpZx6tSHkmCrvpApTQGo67CYDnvprLg5yRME=")
   .add("publicobject.com", "sha256/lCppFqbkrlJ3EcVFAkeip0+44VaoJUymbnOaEUk7tEU=")
   .build();
```

### EVERYTHING PAST HERE IS FOR OLDER (2.x) VERSIONS OF OKHTTP

After reading [this blog post](http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html) I was able to modify the concept for use with OkHttp. You should use at least version 2.0 if you want to avoid using a global SSL context.

This modification applies only to the current instance of OkHttp, and changes that instance so that it **only** accepts certificates from the certificate specified. If you want other certificates (such as one from Twitter) to be accepted, you simply need to create a new OkHttp instance without the modifications described below.

### 1. Creating a TrustStore

In order to pin a certificate, you first need to create a truststore containing this certificate. To create the truststore we will use this handy script from nelenkov slightly modified for our purposes:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
  echo "Usage: importcert.sh <CA cert PEM file> <bouncy castle jar> <keystore pass>"
  exit 1
fi

CACERT=$1
BCJAR=$2
SECRET=$3

TRUSTSTORE=mytruststore.bks
ALIAS=`openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash -noout -in $CACERT`

if [ -f $TRUSTSTORE ]; then
    rm $TRUSTSTORE || exit 1
fi

echo "Adding certificate to $TRUSTSTORE..."
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias $ALIAS \
      -file $CACERT \
      -keystore $TRUSTSTORE -storetype BKS \
      -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
      -providerpath $BCJAR \
      -storepass $SECRET

echo "" 
echo "Added '$CACERT' with alias '$ALIAS' to $TRUSTSTORE..."
```

To run this script you need 3 things:

1. Make sure `keytool` (included in Android SDK) is on your $PATH.
2. Make sure you have the latest BouncyCastle jar file download in the same dir as the script. (Download [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar))
3. The certificate you want to pin.

Now run the script

```
./gentruststore.sh your_cert.pem bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar your_secret_pass
```

Type 'yes' to trust the certificate, and when complete `mytruststore.bks` will be generated in your current dir.

### 2. Apply your TrustStore to your Android project

Create a directory `raw` under your `res` folder. Copy `mytruststore.bks` here.

Now here's a very simple class that pins your cert to OkHttp

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;


/**
 * Created by martin on 02/06/14.
 */
public class Pinning {

    Context context;
    public static String TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD = "your_secret";
    private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://api.yourdomain.com/";

    public Pinning(Context c) {
        this.context = c;
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory getPinnedCertSslSocketFactory(Context context) {
        try {
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mytruststore);
            trusted.load(in, TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                    TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(trusted);
            sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyApp", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void makeRequest() {
        try {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.setSslSocketFactory(getPinnedCertSslSocketFactory(context));

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ENDPOINT)
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            Log.d("MyApp", response.body().string());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyApp", e.getMessage(), e);

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see we instantiate a new instance of `OkHttpClient` and call `setSslSocketFactory`, passing in a `SSLSocketFactory` with our custom truststore. Make sure you set `TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD` to the password you passed into the shell script.  Your OkHttp instance should now only accept the certificate you specified.

Comment: Please do not create an `OkHttpClient` for every request. Create **a single instance** and re-use it for every request.

Comment: This is sample code, of course you wouldn't do this for every request - notice the url is hardcoded as well.

Comment: thanks. what's the benefit of the password? someone can just rip my APK and see the password anyways. Is there a way to create a store without requiring a password?

Comment: As far as I understand the certificate is not something you're supposed to keep private. Your server sends it to the client for each SSL handshake. In this case a password is required because the `keytool` usually is made for storing private keys, not certs. Unfortunately there is no way to disable passwords so use anything you like.

Comment: @JakeWharton When we have a single instance of OkHttpClient and try to make parallel/concurrent requests from different background threads (also by using enqueue ), the requests are still synchronised and responses are also received one by one. Is there anyway to overcome this behaviour by using only a single instance of okhttpclient?

Comment: Wonderful answer! Except it's outdated now with okhttp3:
````OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
   .sslSocketFactory(getPinnedCertSslSocketFactory(context))
   .build();````

Comment: This does not actually **pin** a certificate. This adds your cert as root certificate. Which means that every certificate signed with the one you've added is also valid.

Comment: @agent_l that's incorrect. It will only accept this one certificate you've created. All other certificates will be invalid.

Comment: @MartinKonecny I've tested your way with BKS (created with portecle) and the result is same: root cert in BKS, derived cert on website and connection is established while it should not be.

Comment: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: How to get hashes for OKHTTP 3 via command line or other tools?

Comment: @SebastianRoth openssl x509 -inform der -in <certificate> -pubkey -noout | openssl rsa -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64  
outputs a sha1 in base64 of your public key if that is what your were looking for...

Comment: People with pem file can use openssl x509 -inform pem -in <certificate> -pubkey -noout | openssl rsa -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64 thanx to @estoke

Comment: @sajadabbasi that's one of the downfalls of certificate pinning in general

Comment: @MartinKonecny ins't there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: how to generate Hash key ..?

Answer (score 27):

This is easier than I thought with OkHttp.

Follow these steps:

**1. Get the public sha1 keys.**
The [OkHttp documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/CertificatePinner.html) gives us a clear way to do this complete with sample code. In case it goes away, here it is pasted in below:

For example, to pin https://publicobject.com, start with a broken
configuration:

```
String hostname = "publicobject.com";
CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
    .add(hostname, "sha1/BOGUSPIN")
    .build();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setCertificatePinner(certificatePinner);

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("https://" + hostname)
    .build();
client.newCall(request).execute();
```

As expected, this fails with a certificate pinning exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate pinning failure!
>   Peer certificate chain:
>   sha1/DmxUShsZuNiqPQsX2Oi9uv2sCnw=: CN=publicobject.com, OU=PositiveSSL
>   sha1/SXxoaOSEzPC6BgGmxAt/EAcsajw=: CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
>   sha1/blhOM3W9V/bVQhsWAcLYwPU6n24=: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
>   sha1/T5x9IXmcrQ7YuQxXnxoCmeeQ84c=: CN=AddTrust External CA Root

Pinned certificates for publicobject.com:

> sha1/BOGUSPIN
>   at com.squareup.okhttp.CertificatePinner.check(CertificatePinner.java)
>   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java)
>   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java)
>   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java)

Follow up by pasting the public key hashes from the exception into the certificate pinner's configuration:

Side note: If you are doing this on Android you will get a separate exception if you are doing this on a UI thread, so make sure you do this on a background thread.

**2. Configure your OkHttp Client:**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setCertificatePinner(new CertificatePinner.Builder()
       .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/DmxUShsZuNiqPQsX2Oi9uv2sCnw=")
       .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/SXxoaOSEzPC6BgGmxAt/EAcsajw=")
       .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/blhOM3W9V/bVQhsWAcLYwPU6n24=")
       .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/T5x9IXmcrQ7YuQxXnxoCmeeQ84c=")
       .build());
```

That's all there is to it!

Comment: +1 for the solution, however retrofit is not using the OkHttpClient I am setting with CertificatePinner, any idea?

Comment: @dhaval You can use the retrofit builder, and supply an OkHttpClient to it.

Comment: cool! If my site certificate is going to expire in a month and I want both the old cert and the new one to work once its live can I add both certificate pins in my app?

Comment: @Bootstrapper I'm not an expert in this by any means. But I just went through this process. I worked with my IT team, and they swapped out the certificates on a test environment, and I was able to connect just fine to it. From my testing, I found that as long as at least one of the certificates matched, the request would still succeed. You should do your own testing though, as I only tested this very briefly, and we ended up taking a measure that didn't rely on this approach.

Comment: Well, this technically is pinning a **hash**, not a certificate itself. Why open yourself to a collision attack, even if it's purely hypothetical?

Comment: That seems ridiculous to me, but if you aren't comfortable with it, don't pin a hash.

Comment: i am getting this exception instead of the one with the sha256, any idea how to remedy? `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

Comment: ok seems like it may be server side, when using my UAT server it gives that error, but against my prod server its ok, so must be the way the certificates are setup on the server, not sure how that works though, maybe someone can clarify

Comment: @Fonix Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 17):

If you don't have access to the domain (restricted access for example) and cant test bogus hash, but you have certificate file you can use openssl to retrieve it:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -pubkey -noout | openssl rsa -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

Comment: If your certificate is already a der (eg. if taken from chrome), the command is `openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -fingerprint -sha256 -noout | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64`

Comment: Be careful, and make sure to use -pubkey (-fingerprint will create a sha256 for the entire cert which is incorrect)

Answer (score 6):

To expand on the sample [source code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/83090befcca69b44c257b96afb519ca66282ca63/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/CertificatePinner.java#L43) @Michael-barany shared, I have done some testing and it appears to be a misleading code sample. In the sample the code the exception noted 4 sha1 hashes from the certificate chain exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate pinning failure!
Peer certificate chain:
sha1/DmxUShsZuNiqPQsX2Oi9uv2sCnw=: CN=publicobject.com, OU=PositiveSSL
sha1/SXxoaOSEzPC6BgGmxAt/EAcsajw=: CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
sha1/blhOM3W9V/bVQhsWAcLYwPU6n24=: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
sha1/T5x9IXmcrQ7YuQxXnxoCmeeQ84c=: CN=AddTrust External CA Root
```

then subsequently added all 4 sha1 public key hashes to the CertificatePinner Builder.

```
CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
.add("publicobject.com", "sha1/DmxUShsZuNiqPQsX2Oi9uv2sCnw=")
.add("publicobject.com", "sha1/SXxoaOSEzPC6BgGmxAt/EAcsajw=")
.add("publicobject.com", "sha1/blhOM3W9V/bVQhsWAcLYwPU6n24=")
.add("publicobject.com", "sha1/T5x9IXmcrQ7YuQxXnxoCmeeQ84c=")
.build();
```

However, given tests I have performed and reviewing the code, only the first valid one would be interpreted, so you would be best suited to only include ONE of the hashes returned. You could use the most specific hash "DmxUShsZuNiqPQsX2Oi9uv2sCnw" for the precise site certificate... or you could use the most broad hash "T5x9IXmcrQ7YuQxXnxoCmeeQ84c" for the CA Root based on your desired security posture.

Comment: You would have to post this to Square's github, but I think the author's intent was to have fallback hashes in case perhaps the certificate needed to be revoked and replaced it wouldn't cause havoc on existing client code. Again, that's just my thoughts.

Comment: @MichaelBarany, FWIW [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.m#L280) for iOS supports both validating that each pinned certificate is in the chain and validating that at least one pinned certificate is in the chain. I'm not an expert on which is more ideal, but it's nice to have that flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

I found the example mentioned in **Unknown certificate authority** section of this link [developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) very useful.

The SSLSocketFactory returned in context.getSocketFactory() can be then used to set to OkHttpClient in setSslSocketFactory() method.

Note : The Unknown certificate authority section also mentions the link to download a cert file to use and check this code.

Here is the sample method I've written to obtain the SSLSocketFactory

```
private SSLSocketFactory getSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
        // Load CAs from an InputStream
        // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        // From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
        InputStream caInput = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.loadder);
        Certificate ca = null;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        if (ca == null)
            return null;
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Later I'm just setting this to OkHttpClient like this

```
httpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
```

and then make the https call

```
httpClient.newCall(requestBuilder.build()).enqueue(callback);
```