# SSL: 400 no required certificate was sent

Tags: java, oracle, ssl

**The code and inputs**

I'm trying to establish SSL connection and I'm getting `400 No required SSL certificate was sent` response from the server. I'm doing this in a standard way like it's described for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007536); I run Java 8.

The sample of my code would be:

```
    OkHttpClient client     = new OkHttpClient();
    KeyStore keyStoreClient = getClientKeyStore();
    KeyStore keyStoreServer = getServerKeyStore();
    String algorithm        = ALGO_DEFAULT;//this is defined as "PKIX"

    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStoreClient, PASSWORD_SERVER.toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStoreServer);

    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

    client.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    client.setConnectTimeout(32, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
    client.setReadTimeout(32, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    // socket timeout

    return client;
```

And here is the code that I use to send GET-request:

```
public String get(String url) throws IOException
{
    String callUrl  = URL_LIVE.concat(url);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(callUrl)
            .build();
    Response response = this.client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
```

I enabled:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
```

So to see debug messages - but there's no errors/warnings/alerts there, the only thing is in the very end:

```
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
main, called closeSocket(true)
```

Which is the only thing I can treat as "abnormal" stuff (but I doubt it is).

**I tried:**

- Different protocols disabling/enabling. For instance, forcing `TLSv1` / `TLSv1.1` for the socket with no success. To try that I wrapped my ssl factory into another factory which disables/enables certain protocols.
- Disabling `SSLv2Hello` - but it doesn't change the picture.
- Install [Oracle policies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) because before there were notices about some skipped algorithms and this installation "solved" that but the overall result is still same.
- Setting `System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");` - lame, but also didn't change a thing apart from message in the log `Allow unsafe renegotiation: true` (was "false" obviously)
- Using `KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()` as `algorithm` for `KeyManagerFactory.getInstance()` call. That raises exception `Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded` and as far as I got the idea, it's because of wrong algorithm used (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053459/2637490)). My default algorithm is: `SunX509`
- Adding the certificate directly to my machine with `keytool -importcert -file /path/to/certificate -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"` and then using this in my program via `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/path/to/keystore.jks");` with setting password: `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","mypassword");` (I set password in `keytool` after which confirmed trusted certificate with `yes`); see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326346/2637490) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5871352/2637490) posts. No errors were raised with this - but issue persisted.
- Adding the certificate to the global keystore (the one located in `JAVA_PATH/jre/lib/security/cacerts`) with: `keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias Alias -file /path/to/certificate` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27928213/2637490)); looks like import operation was successful but it didn't change the picture

There's also notice in debug: `ssl: KeyMgr: choosing key: 1 (verified: OK)` - not sure if it's relevant as I'm not SSL expert.

Unfortunately I can not see the server-side logs so I can't observe the full picture.

**Question**

What can be the reason for this 400 error and how can I progress further (debug/try something else) ? Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have a client certificate unless you have created (1) a keypair and (2) a self signed certificate or (3) a CSR and (4) had it signed by a CA, and none of those operations can validly be carried out in the JDK's truststore.

Comment: I have a client certificate in pkcs12 format. I tried to export it which actually was successful with `keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore  -srckeystore cert -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass certPass -alias 1` and I know that `certPass` which is valid since I'm able to unlock pkcs12 cert with it and see certificate + private key in there

Comment: I found the problem. It's like @EJP says, self-signed cert. I fixed all for now.

Answer (score 8):

Your server is asking for a client-side certificate. You need to install a certificate (signed by a trusted authority) on your client machine, and let your program know about it.

Typically, your server has a certificate (with the key purpose set to "TLS server authentication") signed by either your organization's IT security or some globally trusted CA. You should get a certificate for "TLS client authentication" from the same source.

If you capture the TLS handshake in Wireshark, you'll see the ServerHello message followed by a "Client Certificate Request", to which you reply with a "Client Certificate" message with length 0. Your server chooses to reject this.

Comment: I have a certificate and I did: `keytool -importcert -file /path/here -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"` after which I set up password. In my program I did: `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/path/to/jks");` and `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");` but I still have same issue. Am I doing import correct? Tried from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325263/how-to-import-a-cer-certificate-into-a-java-keystore) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5871352/2637490)