# How to add a certificate to PhpStorm?

Tags: php, error-handling, certificate

I have downloaded PhpStorm to get data from a website that uses a certificate that is given by the company, but the problem is that when I try to connect to it, I end up with this error :

> 400 No required SSL certificate was
> sent
>
> ## 400 Bad
> Request
>
> No required SSL certificate was
> sent
>
> ---
>
> nginx

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: what is the context ? are you trying to connect to a git repo , are you trying to run code (if yes show it).

Comment: this makes reference to my post right here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65437314/how-to-get-data-from-a-website-that-uses-ssl-using-curl-and-php thus, this is another post about the same problem, but it could help people answer their question.

Comment: please dont duplicate your posts, there is enough noise around here.

Comment: @edoode You have `nginx` there in your quoted message. Not sure how it's related to PhpStorm. But anyway: if it's an actual PhpStorm that complains about unknown/self-signed certificate or alike (e.g. built-in REST client or alike) .. then look here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-tools-server-certificates.html

Comment: this doesn't answer my question, I said that its a complement of my previous question. this question can help people understanding if IDE related or in-code related

Comment: @edoode Looking at your original question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/65437314/783119) -- that looks like the certificate is may actually be needed from your end (to be sent as part of the request) .. or some misconfiguration/issue on the target site. Right now this issue does not seem to have anything to do with PhpStorm.

Comment: @LazyOne so this means that I have to put my cert somewhere in my code in order to make it work properly ?

Comment: @edoode Good question. I'll be honest -- I do not know as I have never dealt with such issue myself (not in HTTP request at very least). I may only suggest to check the documentation and coding examples/requirements for the service that you are trying to use. If they have exampels for PHP then they should have mention such  requirements somewhere at the "get started/requirements" stage.

Comment: @edoode  If they have examples in other languages (e.g. cURL request or an actual another lang) then you may look and test how they work (to confirm if it's an issue on your PHP code or something else). Right now I have no idea what `nginx` is reporting this -- your own/proxy ... or the actual target service. In any case: consider contacting the Support of the target service -- they should better know how their service works and what that issue could mean.