# Square okHTTP certificate pinning - sslSocketFactory error

Tags: android, client-certificates, okhttp, pinning, sslsocketfactory

I am trying to import my own BKS file, which contains my self signed certificate but I am running into trouble with okHTTP. I want to do this with the bks file, I also got it working via the sha512/.

I ve got this code from several tutorials and I know there the problem is, but cant fix it.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class Pinning
{
    Context context;
    public static String TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD = "your_secret";
    private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://api.yourdomain.com/";

public Pinning(Context c) {
    this.context = c;
}

private SSLSocketFactory getPinnedCertSslSocketFactory(Context context) {
    try {
        KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mytruststore);
        trusted.load(in, "mypass".toCharArray());
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trusted);
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyApp", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}


public void makeRequest() {
    try {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().sslSocketFactory(getPinnedCertSslSocketFactory(this.context));

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(ENDPOINT)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        Log.d("MyApp", response.body().string());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyApp", e.getMessage(), e);

    }
}
}
```

Now I am getting the following error within the following line:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().sslSocketFactory(getPinnedCertSslSocketFactory(this.context)).;
```

ERROR:

SSLSocketFactory in okHTTPClient cannt be applied to javax.net.SSLSocketFactory.

If you look within the imports you see the following 3 from javax.

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
```

So i got a missmatch. Seems like I need an okHTTP - sslSocketFactory with my bks file. But I cant find a working explanation to that. I am also using okHTTP 3.3.1

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
```

I found that explanation/solution here: [How can I pin a certificate with Square OKHTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006545/how-can-i-pin-a-certificate-with-square-okhttp). As mentioned before. I want to use the bks file, not the sha512/ method.

Therefore I need to know, how to parse that javax.ssl.Factory into the okHTTP-sslFactory or how to create an okHTTPsslFactory with the generate bks file.

Furthermore the method setSSLSocketFactory is not available anymore in okHTTP 3.1.1.

I really appreciate your help and thanks for taking the time to get through this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following syntax instead

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
             .sslSocketFactory(getPinnedCertSslSocketFactory(this.context))
             .build();
```

Comment: Oh man thank you! I am retard! I have forgotton to add the .Builder(). Shame on me :/